# Treat ssh terminal like it is local?

Tags: command-line, ssh, gui

I'm trying to work on a computer remotely, but some of what I want to do involves calling GUI programs. I want them to open on the physical display of the remote laptop.

Essentially my question is how can I ssh into machine and open firefox or nautilus.

Whenever I try commands I get

```
server@hyrule:~$ gnome-terminal
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
server@hyrule:~$ firefox
Error: no display specified
server@hyrule:~$ nautilus
Could not parse arguments: Cannot open display:
server@hyrule:~$
```

I just want the session to be treated like its local.

Comment: I got it working with the 2 commands below. I make those into a bash file and made a cronjob, that won't work. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this daily by running

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

before invoking the program itself.  Note that if you're logged in as a different user locally vs. remotely, you may need to use `xhost` to allow the remote user permission to do this.

Comment: I just run `export DISPLAY=:0` (or prepend a command with `DISPLAY=:0`). I've never needed the `.0` on the end.